# Drupal 7 : drupal_mail function does not send mail more than 12 recipients

Tags: email, drupal

We have developed a meeting room module where we are sending invitation to invitees. But We are not able to send mail invitation more than 12 recipients.

Answer (score 0):

There no reason here to think this 12 limit comes from Drupal.
Suggested steps are:

- Write and test a very basic function sending mail to 13 or more recipients (better to use validated email address)
- Check your Drupal dblog
- Check then your mail server log

Answer (score 0):

There was mail_logger module which was installed in system already. I increased the field "mailto" to VARCHAR(2047) in the mail_logger.install file.

Please refer below patch:

https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2549049-3.patch
After above changes done in mail_logger.install file run update.php to get new updates done in database.

That's It!!! Check now!! :)